# Cannot open shell script files on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

On ubuntu 15.04 64 bit, I cannot properly run a .sh file shell script file. Instead of opening the application like it's supposed to, it opens the Libreoffice writer with the script code. The program I was trying to run was the singularity viewer for second life 64 bit. If anyone can help me fix this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the executable flag is set for that file?

You can also run it from command line even without the executable flag set:

```
source <path/yourscript.sh>
```

Also, you should make sure that the first line of the script is `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+T opens a Terminal, type ^-- that at the `$` prompt. Also remember prepend the path if the script isn't in the list shown by `ls`